# Module dependencies: is it possible to set a mininum version?

Tags: module, version, raku

Is it possible to add a minimum version to a module listed in the `depend` section of a `META6.json` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare a dependency on `Foo` of version 1 or higher one would do the same as if one was asking zef to install `Foo:ver<1.0+>`:

```
zef install "Foo:ver<1.0+>"
```

```
"depends" : [
    "Foo:ver<1.0+>"
]
```

---

Long form identities use version literals for `api` and `ver` attributes, and strings for any other (such as `auth`, `file`, `name`, etc). So to describe such a dependency you should write it the same way you would if you were `use`ing it using the literal form `:foo<...>` ala `use Test:ver<6.d+>`. This is opposed to `:foo(...)` form which can run anything, e.g. `use Test:ver(do { say 42; v6.d+ })`, which would allow arbitrary code execution by just searching for dependencies and thus is not a valid way to describe something in a META6.json

Answer (score 6):

It uses the same syntax as [the `Version` class](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Version). You can use, for instance, `v1.0+`, or, in META6.json, simply "1.0+"

Comment: How would I append the version to the module name: `..., "depends" : [ "Required::Modul:ver<1.0+>" ], ...` ?

Comment: @sid_com that's correct. See also ugexe's answer above.